# cleared custom filter but unable redraw datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I created a custom filter for my datatable.  The filter works accordingly; I can enter some text, and the datatable will find any matching records.

The problem is, if a user enters text, navigates to another screen, then comes back to the datatable page, the datatable is still displaying the records returned from the filter search, even though the text in the filter search is no longer visible.

The user can click into the filter and press the backspace button to clear the search, but they should not have to do that.

I have tried the following:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $('.searchFilter').val('');  // <-- clears the customer search filter
  $('input[type=search]').val(''); // <-- thought this would help
  var table = $('#example1').DataTable();
  table.search('').draw(); // <-- redraw the datatable
});
```

The above does not work.

I even tried this:

```
$(window).on('load', function()
{
  // same code as above
});
```

Unfortunately, that does not work either.

Am I missing something?  Why doesn't the datatable reload?  How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would clear the table to start so then you won't have this issue.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $('.searchFilter').val('');  // <-- clears the customer search filter
  $('input[type=search]').val(''); // <-- thought this would help
  var table = $('#example1').DataTable();
  table.clear() // <-- table is cleared
  table.search('').draw(); // <-- redraw the datatable
});
```

Comment: What happens when you debug it and step through it. After table.clear(), does it clear the table?

Comment: The table does not clear.  It doesn't make any sense.

Comment: When you do console.log(table) does all the table data come back?

Comment: I just found the problem.... stateSave was set to true...  smh....  I'm so disappointed with myself....  I'll give you an upvote for taking the time to help me.  Thank you, sir.

Comment: Glad you figured it out!